# Batch script remove last specific file extension or use special replacement rules

Tags: windows, batch, file-extension

How do I setup a .bat script to remove and replace a specific file extension from all files in current folder with the following replacement logic?

**Simply what I want is always remove last extension

and only do this when the last extension is exactly matching ".hhll"**

---

otherwise as different approach for the same result:
New file extension replacement text should be defined for all of these files individually with current text between file extension dot at the end and the next dot before file extension dot.
(number of characters between these 2 dots varies)

EXAMPLE:

(**DOT** is actually . in the file names)
current folder content:
fontmap**DOT**txt**DOT**hhll
fontmap**DOT**txt**DOT**envm**DOT**hhll

the .bat script must replace only hhll extensions with this as final result:
fontmap.txt  --> txt is new file extension
fontmap.txt.envm  --> envm is new file extension

Answer (score 0):

Okay, second idea to handle this is perhaps unnecessarily overcomplicated.
For the **simple idea** it's in my situation enough to remove all possible instances of **.hhll**.

```
for %%F in (*hhll*) do ( set "name=%%F" ren "!name!" "!name:.hhll=!" )
```